# How to run functionnal/unit tests only

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

As we already know in Play, every tests (unit and functional) sit in the test folder. How can we mark our functional and unit tests in a way that we can run only functional tests in one run and only unit tests in another run?

And I would like to achieve this without having a package for each type (meaning test/unit/... and test/functional/...). The problem with this solution is let's say you have a app/auth folder (so a auth package). Your unit tests would be in package unit/auth and would not be able to see any package private methods/fields/classes.

What is the right way to do this? How does Play expects us to achieve this?

IMO, the best way to do that would be having two test folders, one for unit, one for functional. But I'm afraid it would break the `sbt test` and related tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing in Play is based on sbt

You can configure your `build.sbt` with test filters:

`testOptions in Test := Seq(Tests.Filter(name => name contains "IntegrationTest"))`

So something like this would allow you to run `sbt custom:test` and it would only run those tests that pass the `TestsFilter` predicate.

```
lazy val CustomIntTest = config("custom") extend Test

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .configs(CustomIntTest)
  .settings(inConfig(CustomIntTest)(Defaults.testTasks):_*)
  .settings(
    testOptions in CustomIntTest := Seq(Tests.Filter(name => name.contains("Identifier")))
  )
```

e.g. `MyCoolIdentifierTest` would run, but `MyCoolTest` or `MyCoolidentifierTest` would not. One thing that's cool is `sbt test` would still run all tests including your custom filter

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final build.sbt config using @tgk answer.

```
lazy val AcceptanceTestConfig = config("acceptance") extend Test
lazy val UnitTestConfig = config("unit") extend Test

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .configs(AcceptanceTestConfig)
  .settings(inConfig(AcceptanceTestConfig)(Defaults.testTasks):_*)
  .settings(
     testOptions in AcceptanceTestConfig := Seq(Tests.Filter(name => name.contains("Acceptance")))
   )
  .configs(UnitTestConfig)
  .settings(inConfig(UnitTestConfig)(Defaults.testTasks):_*)
  .settings(
     testOptions in UnitTestConfig := Seq(Tests.Filter(name => !name.contains("Acceptance")))
   )
```

Letting us run `sbt acceptance:test`and `sbt unit:test`